# Check for duplicated names in a list element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists, nested-sortable

### Question:

How to check duplicated names/items in a list element?

### My situation:

I've got a list within a list, here is an example:

```
<ol class="sortable ui-sortable">
<li id="category_1"><div>Car</div>
   <ol>
       <li id="category_2"><div>Color</div>
            <ol>
                <li id="category_3"><div>Red</div></li>
                <li id="category_4"><div>Black</div></li>
            </ol>
       </li>
   </ol>
</li>
<li id="category_5"><div>Motor</div>
   <ol>
       <li id="category_6"><div>Red</div></li>
       <li id="category_7"><div>Black</div></li>
   </ol>
</li>
<li id="category_9"><div>Truck</div></li>
</ol>
```

*The `class="sortable ui-sortable"` that is being used is the for the [NestedSortable jQuery Plugin](https://github.com/mjsarfatti/nestedSortable). So list items are dragable.*

I want to check the names within those divs, when the div is dragged into another list `<ol>`. If this list contains a duplicate, it would highlight in red.

For exampe if I drag `Red` - `category_6` to the `ol` within `Color` - `category_2`, which allready contains a Red, the place (dropspot) turns red. If the user decides to still drop it on that place, the list returns to its original position. `category_6` will than be moved back to the `ol` beneath `category_5`.

So the list could end up like this, or something else if you have a better way:

```
<ol class="sortable ui-sortable">
<li id="category_1"><div>Car</div>
   <ol>
       <li id="category_2"><div>Color</div>
            <ol>
                <li id="category_3"><div>Red</div></li>
                <li id="category_4"><div>Black</div></li>
                <li id="category_6" class="HIGHLIGHTED"><div>Red</div></li>
            </ol>
       </li>
   </ol>
</li>
<li id="category_5"><div>Motor</div>
   <ol>
       <li id="category_7"><div>Black</div></li>
   </ol>
</li>
<li id="category_9"><div>Truck</div></li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start. A function that receives a list and returns the first `li` with a repeated `.text()`. You tagged the question as jQuery, which made it easier.

```
function checkListForDuplicates(ol) {
    var $lis = $(ol).children("li"),
    found = [],
    i;
    for (i = 0; i < $lis.length; i++) {
        text = $($lis[i]).text();
        if ($.inArray(text, found)) {
            return $lis[i];
        } else {
            found.push(text);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering my list to be

```
<ul id="myid">
    <li>apple</li>
    <li>ibm</li>
    <li>apple</li>
    <li>microsoft</li>
    <li>ibm</li>
</ul>
```

The script for finding the duplicates I suggest would be

```
var liText = '',
liList = $('#myid li'),
listOfDuplicate = [];
$(liList).each(function () {
var text = $(this).text();
if (liText.indexOf('|' + text + '|') == -1) liText += '|' + text + '|';
else listOfDuplicate.push($(this));
});

$(listOfDuplicate).each(function () {
     alert("Duplicates :  " + $(this).text());
});
```

Example using [**`fiddle`**](http://jsfiddle.net/gopinaghr/PYdsm/57/)

Comment: Your fiddle example keeps initializing, unless the page is interrupted.

Answer (score 0):

**SEE EDIT BELOW**

I am sure you will need to use the :contains() selector.

```
$('div').mouseup(function(){
    var temp = $(this).text();
    var others = $(this).parent().siblings().children('div:contains('+temp+')');
    if(others.size() > 0){
        $(this).addClass('highlighted');
    }else{
        $(this).removeClass();
    }
});
```

That is what I came up with, but it doesn't work :(

Maybe someone can build on it: http://jsfiddle.net/QQ3JD/

**EDIT :**
I came back to it and got it working: http://jsfiddle.net/mobabur94/QQ3JD/1/

```
function checkContents(){
    $("div").each(function(){
        var temp = $(this).text();
        var others = $(this).parent().siblings().children('div:contains('+temp+')');
        if(others.size() > 0){
            $(this).addClass('highlighted');
        }else{
            $(this).removeClass('highlighted');
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    checkContents();
    $('.sortable').mousemove(function(){
        $("div").each(function(){
            var temp = $(this).text();
            var others = $(this).parent().siblings().children('div:contains('+temp+')');
            if(others.size() > 0){
                $(this).addClass('highlighted');
            }else{
                $(this).removeClass('highlighted');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

It's probably crazy but every time the mouse moves over the list, it performs the check.. There may be a better way of doing this.